# Hive UDF to generate all possible ordered combinations from the list

Tags: hive, udf

I am trying to figure out in Hive how to generate a UDF that would take as input a list and output a list with 2 way ordered combination all elements in the list

**Input:**
list_variable_b

[5142430,5146974,5141766]

**Output:**
list_variable_b

[(5142430,5146974),(5146974,5141766),(5142430,5141766)]

Comment: You could do it using pyhive

Answer (score 3):

So you're asking how to write an UDF that can take an `array<bigint>` and 
turn it into an `array<struct<int,int>` or `array<array<int>`.
It sounds you want what's called n take k, which will produce (n!)/(n-k)!k! elements.

Now, hive has two kinds of UDFs, one that's the simple one, that can only process primitive (non-collection) types. But here you are processing an array so you'll need a Generic UDF. Generic UDF can do much more than simple UDFs, but they are also more difficult to write. A good guide on how to do it is here: http://www.baynote.com/2012/11/a-word-from-the-engineers/

Another way would be to use a double `LATERAL VIEW` with the caveat that all the elements in the array have to be unique for this to work.
If the table is

```
 create table xx ( col  array<int>);
```

such that

```
select * from xx;
OK
[5142430,5146974,5141766]
```

Using a double lateral view to do the cartesian product of the array on itself, then only get the pairs where one element is bigger then the other:

```
 select a1,b1 from xx 
   lateral view explode(col) a as a1 
   lateral view explode(col) b as b1 where a1 < b1;

5142430 5146974
5141766 5142430
5141766 5146974
```

Comment: in 2nd row (5141766, 5142430); a1 < b1 condition does not satisfy

Comment: why not ? 5141766 is < 5142430

Comment: Thanks @RobertoCongiu